# How to create object and send it to OnPost in Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

How to create object and send it to OnPost in Razor Pages?

```
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Add Text</label>
        <input asp-for=SentimentData.SentimentText class="form-control" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>

public void OnPost(SentimentData SentimentData)
{
   Text = SentimentData.SentimentText;
   Analysis.Evaluate(mlContext, Model, SplitDataView.TestSet);
   Analysis.UseModelWithSingleItem(mlContext, SentimentData, Model, Text);
}
```

But after my input field SentimentText is null. i dont know why.

Comment: You should study how model binding works in Razor Pages, perhaps use bound properties rather than parameters to handlers: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: Can you share how to define `SentimentData` in pagemodel?